# ClientBase EndPoint Binding SendTimeout ReceiveTimeout: how to change while debugging

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm developing a solution with a WCF service and a client that uses the service. Sometimes I'm debugging the service, sometime the client, and sometimes both.

During debugging I get a TimeoutException with additional information

**Additional information: The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9950000. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.**

The reason if of course that my server is waiting at a breakpoint instead of answering the question.

During debugging I want longer timeouts, preferably without creating a new configuration for my service client, because if other values of this configuration would change, the changer would have to remember that a special configuration for debugging was created.

I think it is something like:

```
private IMyServiceInterface CreateServiceChannel()
{
    var myServiceClient = new MyServiceClient(); // reads from configuration file
    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        // Increase timeouts to enable slow debugging
        ...
    }
    return (IMyServiceInterface)myServiceClient;
}
```

According to [MSDN Binding.SendTimeout Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.sendtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) is used for something else:

> SendTimeout gets or sets the interval of time provided for a write operation to complete before the transport raises an exception.

Therefore I'd rather not change this value if not needed.

- Is SendTimeout really the best timeout to increase, or is there something like a TransactionTimeout, the timeout between my question and the receipt of the answer?
- How to change the timeout programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article [All WCF timouts explained](http://www.rauch.io/2015/06/25/all-wcf-timeouts-explained/) states that indeed there is something like a transaction timeout: *IContextChannel.OperationTimeout*

> The operation timeout covers the whole service call (sending the request, processing it and receiving a reply). In other words, it defines the maximum time a service call is active from a client’s point of view. If not set, WCF initializes the operation timeout with the configured send timeout.

This explains why the TimeoutException that is thrown advises to change the send timeout.

However, it is possible to change the operation timeout without changing the send timeout:

```
var myServiceClient = new MyServiceClient(); // reads from configuration file

if (Debugger.IsAttached)
{   // Increase timeouts to enable slow debugging:
    IContextChannel contextChannel = (IContextChannel)myServiceClient.InnerChannel;
    // InnerChannel is of type IClientChannel, which implements IContextChannel

    // set the operation timeout to a long value, for example 3 minutes:
    contextChannel.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
}
return (IMyInterface)myService;
```